# Main Menu is not displaying properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, blogs

In my blogger website second line of main menu is not displaying correctly.First line is working fine, second line is also working fine but not displaying correctly when i moves mouse pointer on second line buttons than they displays but in general looks completely white.
My website link - [Click Here](https://www.iaritoppers.com/)
HTML codes-

```
.social-text .snapchat a:after {
    content: "Snapchat"
}

.social-text .email a:after {
    content: "Email"
}

.social-text .external-link a:after {
    content: "WebSite"
}

#header-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0
}

.header-header {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0
}

.header-header .container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0
}

.header-logo {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0
}

.header-logo .header-image-wrapper {
    display: block
}

.header-logo img {
    max-width: 120%;
    max-height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 70px
}

.header-logo h1 {
    color: $(title.color);
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0
}

.header-logo p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 5px 0 0
}

.header-ads {
    position: relative;
    float: right
}

.header-ads .widget>.widget-title {
    display: none
}

.header-ads .widget {
    max-width: 100%
}

.header-ads .widget .widget-content {
    width: 728px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90px;
    line-height: 1
}

.header-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: $(main.dark.color);
    border-top: 2px solid $(main.color)
}

.header-menu .container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0
}

#main-menu .widget,
#main-menu .widget>.widget-title {
    display: none
}

#main-menu .show-menu {
    display: block
}

#main-menu {
    position: relative;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 15
}

#main-menu ul>li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: background .17s
}

#main-menu #main-menu-nav>li:hover,
#main-menu #main-menu-nav>li.li-home {
    background-color: $(main.color)
}

#main-menu ul>li>a {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 46px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    transition: color .17s ease
}

#main-menu #main-menu-nav>li>a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700
}

#main-menu ul>li:hover>a {
    color: #fff
}

#main-menu ul>li>ul {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    top: 46px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: $(main.dark.color);
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid $(main.color);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0
}

#main-menu ul>li>ul>li>ul {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin: -2px 0 0
}

#main-menu ul>li>ul>li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    position: relative
}

#main-menu ul>li>ul>li:hover {
    background-color: $(main.color)
}

#main-menu ul>li>ul>li a {
    display: block;
    height: 36px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 36px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    transition: all .17s ease
}

#main-menu ul>li>ul>li:hover>a {
    color: #fff
}

#main-menu ul>li.has-sub>a:after {
    content: '\f107';
    float: right;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px
}

#main-menu ul>li>ul>li.has-sub>a:after {
    content: '\f105';
    float: right;
    margin: 0
}

#main-menu .mega-menu {
    position: static!important
}

#main-menu .mega-menu>ul {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 10px
}

#main-menu .mega-menu>ul.mega-menu-inner {
    overflow: hidden
}

#main-menu ul>li:hover>ul,
#main-menu ul>li>ul>li:hover>ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1
}

#main-menu ul ul {
    transition: all .25s ease
}

.mega-menu-inner .mega-item {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px
}

.mega-menu-inner .mega-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0
}

.mega-content .post-image-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px
}

.mega-content .post-image-link {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0
}

.mega-content .post-title {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 7px 0 5px;
    padding: 0
}

.mega-content .post-title a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    transition: color .17s
}

.mega-content .post-title a:hover {
    color: $(title.hover)
}

.mega-content .post-meta {
    font-size: 11px
}

.no-posts {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center
}

.mega-menu .no-posts {
    line-height: 60px;
    color: $(title.color)
}

.show-search,
.hide-search {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: $(main.color);
    line-height: 46px;
    z-index: 20;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    transition: background .17s ease
}

.show-search:before {
    content: "\f002";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: 400
}

.hide-search:before {
    content: "\f00d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: 400
}

#nav-search {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: $(main.dark.color);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0
}

#nav-search .search-form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    line-height: 46px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0
}

#nav-search .search-input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the better-formatted code to understand your problem?

Comment: i think these codes are sufficient to understand main-menu.

Answer (score 0):

1, you have more menu items right, so you have to reduce font-size, padding from (#main-menu ul > li > a).

2, Or otherwise you can go for a inner scroll.

Comment: can you tell me if i do so than text size in mobile view will affect or not?

Comment: it will remain the same size, or you can increases the size for mobile responsive

Answer (score 0):

```
  .header-menu {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   /* height: 46px; */
   z-index: 10;
   font-size: 13px;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #384a5f;
   border-top: 2px solid #ffd012;
    }

   #main-menu {
   position: relative;
   /* height: 46px; */
   z-index: 15;
    }

   #main-menu ul{
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   }
```

replace this code in your css for each element! i just removed the height for both header and main menu so that the div can expand with the height of her child! added `display:flex`for ul to make height adjust depending on child

Comment: i have pasted the above suggested codes but problem still remains. check my website www.iaritoppers.com

Comment: U need to remove height:46px from  header-menu and main-menu